# The secret dungeon

Tags: cipher

I am locked in a secret room with a bomb inside. There is a door to get out of here. I have only one try to get out of here. There is a note stuck to the door.

```
 you only have One chance. The keY is here. Use this  to decode it.
 Rvynomqkiprcqkursl.

 From kowim
```

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: The title used to include "(my first puzzle)". I've removed that -- this sort of thing doesn't really belong in a puzzle title, nor in the puzzle itself. But congrats on your first puzzle, Macky ben Jonah, and welcome to Puzzling!

Answer (score 8):

The ciphertext is:

> Rvynomqkiprcqkursl

It decodes to:

> `Thepasswordiswater`
>
>  It is a Vigenere cipher, with a key of `you`, which are the capitalized letters in the clue.
>  So I assume you enter the password `water` in the door keypad to get out?

Comment: I am assuming it is correct, but I am not sure if he knows how to mark answers correct. Good job :)

Comment: You can also decode the signature.